# Pagination Issue - Only 4 Items Returned in Each Request (DynamoDB with boto3)

Tags: python, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm facing an issue with paginating through a DynamoDB table to retrieve videos associated with a specific owner. The goal is to get 10 items per request until all videos for the given owner are retrieved. However, the current implementation is returning only 4 items, and it consistently returns the same set of videos for every request.
***Code Overview:***

```
def get_videos_for_owner_id(owner_id, video_id=None, batch_size=10):    

if video_id is None:
    # call repeatedly for pagination
    page_args = {'Limit': batch_size}
    all_items = []
    num_calls = 0
    while True:
        res = my_table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression='owner_id = :xx',
            Select='SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES',                
            ProjectionExpression='video_id,events,last_update,preview,StateMachineArn,video_metadata_key,video_status,files,video_settings',
            ExpressionAttributeValues={':xx':  owner_id},
            **page_args
        )
        num_calls += 1
        
        all_items.extend(res.get('Items'))
        
        if res.get('LastEvaluatedKey', None) is None or len(all_items) >= batch_size:
            break
        else:
            page_args = {'ExclusiveStartKey': res['LastEvaluatedKey'], 'Limit': batch_size}
else:
    res = my_table.get_item(Key={
          'owner_id': owner_id,
          'video_id': video_id
        })
    all_items = res.get('Item', None)
    if all_items is None:
        return []
    all_items = [all_items]
#[c for c in all_items if c['video_id'] == 'video-dfb0ba73-e4b7-47d1-934c-bf4d66959827']
if len(all_items) > 0:
    res = [process_flattened_record(r) for r in all_items]
return res
```

Problem Details:

- The code uses a while loop for pagination, with a specified
  batch_size of 10. Despite the pagination logic, only 4 items are
  returned in each request. The items returned are the same for every
  request, indicating an issue with the pagination or querying logic.
  The DynamoDB query and pagination logic seem correct, but the
  expected number of items is not being fetched.

**Expected Behavior:**

*I want the function to return 10 items per request until all videos associated with the provided owner are retrieved. The pagination logic should iterate through the DynamoDB table correctly, fetching the next set of items.*

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `print(num_calls)` what's the value?

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan 
First iteration:  1
Second iteration:  2
Third iteration:  3

Comment: So it makes 3 calls to DynamoDB? Can you add a `print(page_args)` just before the call to `query()`?

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan I added a print statement for page_args just before the call to the query function. Surprisingly, it printed an empty object, {}. This suggests that the issue might be related to the initial value or modification of page_args?

Additionally, I printed num_calls after the query, and now it shows only two iterations instead of three as before.

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan now, I added a print statement for page_args before the call to the query function and return me this value {'Limit': 10}.

Comment: For every call that's all that is printed? No ExlcusiveStartKey?